# Zend framework leftJoin

Tags: php, zend-framework, left-join

Here is the code that doesn't work.

```
$select = $tariffsTable->select(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::SELECT_WITHOUT_FROM_PART)
                       ->from('tariff', null)
                       ->where('id = ?', $this->id)
                       ->joinLeft('characteristic_value',
                                  'characteristic_value.tariff_id = id',
                                   array('value_' . $locale, 'characteristic_id'))

                       ->joinLeft('characteristic',
                                  'id = characteristic_value.characteristic_id',
                                  array('name_' . $locale, 'alias'));

$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$tariffCharacteristics = $tariffsTable->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
```

Thank you for help! I have solved the problem. Here is working code:

```
    $select = $tariffsTable->select(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::SELECT_WITHOUT_FROM_PART)
                             ->from('tariff', null)

                             ->joinLeft( array('characteristic_value'),
                                        'characteristic_value.tariff_id = tariff.id',
                                        array('value_' . $locale))

                             ->joinLeft(array('characteristic'),
                                        'characteristic.id = characteristic_value.characteristic_id',
                                        array('name_' . $locale, 'alias'))
                             ->where('tariff.id = ?', $this->id);

    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because your are using `id` column on `WHERE` and/or `LEFT JOIN ON` clause while an id column should be present in both table your are trying to join.

You need to specify which id should be used in both case.

Like characteristic.id or characteristic_value.id or tarriff.id.

You can use alias by using array as a parameter for `from()` and `joinLeft()` methods.

```
$select->from(array('t' => 'tarriff'))
    ->where('t.id = ?', $this->id);
```